# Outlook 2007 won't open. Can't find scanpst.exe

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I have Outlook 2007 and "Cannot Start Microsoft Outlook....Error have been detected....".  I have searched everywhere for "Scanpst.exe" to run the Inbox Repair Tool, but it doesn't seem to exist on my computer. Is this possible?

Should I uninstall, and presumably lose everything?

Answer (score 3):

For Outlook 2007, `ScanPST.exe` should be located in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12` (or `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12` on a 64-bit cmoputer).

If it's not there, you may want to do a Repair install of Office/Outlook.

More info:

- [How to use Inbox Repair tool to repair pst file in Outlook](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/272227)
- [How to install the individual 2007 Office features or to repair the installed 2007 Office programs](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/924611)

Comment: +1 for repair. why bother with copy from here to there when a repair fixes nearly everything fast?

Comment: Thanks techie007. Still cant find scanpst.exe. Ran a Microsoft Office diagnostic, but no help. Per your 2nd link, I've tried to repair items in Programs and Features. "Microsoft Outlook Connector" is the only thing that mentions Outlook, but it says "..feature is on a network resource that is unavail..". I appreciate your help!

Comment: If Microsoft Office (or even just Outlook) doesn't appear in your Add/Remove Programs list, then your install is corrupted and you need to (re)install from the Office media.  If you've located your PST files, back them up first.

Comment: It shows Microsoft Office 2007 Primary Interop Assemblies, Microsoft Office Enterprise 2007, M.O. File Validation Add In, M.O. Home and Student 2007, M.O. Live Add In 1.5, M.O. XP Media Content. Should I try to Repair these? I'm out of my league ~

Answer (score 0):

you may want to scan your HDD for errors open command.

> echo Y | Chkdsk /f

Will fix all your errors automatically after restart. use "/r" instead if you want to scan for bad sectors. (may take long time)

Answer (score 0):

If its just a bad profile load,  close outlook and goto appdata/local/microsoft/outlook and rename all of the OST files. This will rebuild the local cache.

You can also try launching outlook with the /resetnavpane switch.

These two things resolve most of the outlook issues I come across.

If its a bad PST,  then run the repair on office like other have suggested. You could also remove the PST from the profile by going to mail im control panel,  data files and remove the PST from there.

Answer (score -1):

In Outlook 2007, ScanPST.exe is located at predefine path i.e. mentioned below:

**32-bit Windows**  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12

**64-bit Windows**  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12

I hope you would be able to find required exe.

Comment: This duplicates another answer and adds no new content. Please don't post an answer unless you actually have something new to contribute.